# HTML5 Capture Attribute on devices image get rotated

Tags: c#, html5-canvas

I have used html5 camera capture attribute, when user try to capture image from the devices image gets rotated

1. Do we need to provide any setting on this?
2. Can we correct the image rotation using C#?

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Answer (score 1):

We are successfully using the following code to capture images and it works fine:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var video = document.getElementById("video")

// Start video code omitted...

// Capture function
canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0);

var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
```

The image should be fine unless there is some specific hardware configuration not allowing this.

And yes, it is possible to rotate the image using C#. Google it.